# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros entre un Tab y un Fragment en Xamarin Android?

Tags: android-fragment, xamarin.android

Tengo un activity donde hay un método que crea 2 Tab, de esos 2 Tab, cada uno manda llamar a un Fragment diferente ¿cómo podría pasar un parámetro del Tab al Fragment?

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MisDatos);
            //Recibir Parámetro 
            Mail = Intent.GetStringExtra("TagMail") ?? "Data not available";
            //Tab de "MisDatos"
            AddTab("Mis Datos", Resource.Drawable.MisDatos, new MiAval(), Mail);
            //Tab de "MiAval" 
            AddTab("Mi Aval", Resource.Drawable.MisDatos, new MisDatosFragment(), Mail);
        }
        //En éste método, donde se crea el Tab, agregue el parámetro de string Mail, y ese es el que se envía al fragment, pero no se cómo recibirlo en el fragment
        void AddTab(string tabText, int iconResourceId, Fragment fragment, string Mail)
        {
            var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab();
            tab.SetText(tabText);
            tab.SetIcon(iconResourceId);
            tab.SetText(Mail); //Éste es el parámetro que quiero pasar
            tab.TabSelected += delegate (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
            {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
            };
            this.ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
        }
```

¿Cómo es que puedo recibir el parámetro en el fragment?

Aquí está mi fragment

```
    View view;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MiAvalFragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta enviandolo por el constructor del fragment cuando lo inicializas:

```
public class MiAval extends Fragment
{
   private String mail;
   public MiAval(String mail)
   {
     this.mail = mail;
   }
    View view;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       // procesas mail
      //...
}
```

Entonces para pasarle el parametro:

```
AddTab("Mis Datos", Resource.Drawable.MisDatos, new MiAval(Mail), Mail);
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por la gran ayuda Einer, siempre me resuelves mis conflictos de Xamarin Android ;)